# I get "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" when trying to play audio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is here.

When clicking "Play" I receive the UnCaughtTypeError "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" within my `togglePlay` function.

[image]

**Javascript Code:**

```
function $(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };
    const media = document.getElementById('audio');

    let ui = {
        play: 'playAudio',
        audio: 'audio',
        percentage: 'percentage',
        seekObj: 'seekObj',
        currentTime: 'currentTime'
    };

    function togglePlay() {
        if (media.paused === false) {
            media.pause();
            $(ui.play).classList.remove('pause');
        } else {
            media.play();
            $(ui.play).classList.add('pause');
        }
    };

    function calculatePercentPlayed() {
        let percentage = (media.currentTime / media.duration).toFixed(2) * 100;
        $(ui.percentage).style.width = `${percentage}%`;
    }

    function calculateCurrentValue(currentTime) {
        const currentMinute = parseInt(currentTime / 60) % 60;
        const currentSecondsLong = currentTime % 60;
        const currentSeconds = currentSecondsLong.toFixed();
        const currentTimeFormatted = `${currentMinute < 10 ? `0${currentMinute}` : currentMinute}:${
        currentSeconds < 10 ? `0${currentSeconds}` : currentSeconds
    }`;

        return currentTimeFormatted;
    }

    function initProgressBar() {
        const currentTime = calculateCurrentValue(media.currentTime);
        $(ui.currentTime).innerHTML = currentTime;
        $(ui.seekObj).addEventListener('click', seek);

        media.onended = () => {
            $(ui.play).classList.remove('pause');
            $(ui.percentage).style.width = 0;
            $(ui.currentTime).innerHTML = '00:00';
        };

        function seek(e) {
            const percent = e.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
            media.currentTime = percent * media.duration;
        }

        calculatePercentPlayed();
    }

    $(ui.play).addEventListener('click', togglePlay)
    $(ui.audio).addEventListener('timeupdate', initProgressBar);
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="audio-player">
                    <audio id="audio">
                        <source src="{{ product.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/mp3">
                    </audio>

                    <div class="player-controls">
                        <div id="radioIcon"></div>
                        <button id="playAudio"></button>
                        <div id="seekObjContainer">
                            <div id="seekObj">
                                <div id="percentage"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p><small id="currentTime">00:00</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I see the issue has something to do with adding the class `.pause` to `ui` but I can't figure out exactly what the issue is. If anyone can help that would be great! And if any additional info is needed please let me know, I'll be happy to provide. Thanks.

Comment: looks like it has to do with `$(ui.play).classList.add('pause');`  The element `$(ui.play)` doesn't have a property `classList` so `$(ui.play).classList.add` throws that error.

Comment: also in your title you say you are using vanilla javascript, but you are using JQuery in your post. Those contradict each other.

Comment: @AndrewLohr there is no jQuery in the post, if you read the code properly you will see where the `$` is defined.

Comment: ah interesting, thanks for catching that

Comment: @Delroy Brown your code works fine for me after adding an extra closing `</div>` and some text to the `playAudio`  button. The `pause` class is added and removed from the `playAudio` button when it is clicked. Try logging `$(ui.play)` where it is failing and see if you get the html element you expect.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLohr, this sounds like the best bet for finding the issue as none of the other options have worked in my favor so far. But thank you all for the responses. Much appreciated!

Comment: you're welcome, you can edit your question with your findings and maybe we can still help out. Just tag me after you edit and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: May be silly, but have you verified that `media` is actually defined?